# Running Yarn in a Trellis + Bedrock + Sage + Vagrant environment

Tags: wordpress, webpack, vagrant, yarnpkg, roots-sage

Learning how to use Vagrant environments!

I'm trying to run Yarn in a Trellis + Bedrock + Sage + Vagrant environment and I keep getting the following error when I run `yarn run start`.

`Couldn't find the binary webpack --hide-modules --watch --config resources/assets/build/webpack.config.js`

I'm not quite sure what I'm doing wrong... I'm running `yarn run start` in the theme directory within my vagrant environment, ie. `vagrant@test:/srv/www/test.io/current/web/app/themes/newTheme`

Comment: do you have a box or a project with the provisioning script where we can reproduce the issue ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to update webpack via npm and I also ran `npm -g install --save-dev` for good measure.